# Phonegap with servlets and database connection java files

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, cordova

I'm testing a phonegap application.. and i need to connect it with my sql database.
I use java for my web app backend hence used jdbc controller to connect with my database.

**My Problem:**  I am developing the phonegap for iOS and android simultaneously. Obviously the front end of the app doesn't change, because phonegap. But i cant figure out where to put my `src` folder, which contains my database connectivity files, servlets and other java classes.

**Question:**

1. Will the `src` folder have to be in the root directory of the project? or does it reside individually inside `platforms>iOS` and `platforms>Android`
2. (Completely detached from the question above) Why are there individual `www` folders `platforms>iOS` and `platforms>Android`, when there is one `www` in the root folder already?

Comment: I guess Phonegap is totally static so you can have another web project which will not have any phonegap files and let phonegap project be pure static project which will use AJAX to communicate with you controller.

Comment: Yes I know, we can't use jsp in phonegap, but I can still use Ajax to access servlets of the same project right?  EDIT: sorry I misunderstood your comment.. Turns out I'll need a separate web app, and phonegap is only static.

Comment: But your server side code base should not be inside the phonegap code base as your phonegap code base will be part your apk file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate your server side code from phonegap code base as whatever code you will have in phonegap will be part of your installation file of app.

So you should have seperate code base for server side and client side.

Comment: Also what about question 2? Why are there multiple copies of www?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood, but it sounds like you are trying to put java source code containing servlets and database access code into the phone gap app? It doesn't go there - it goes in your server side web app. 
Then you use http (probably ajax) to communicate with the server from the phone app.

Comment: So ill need a separate web project for those database classes? And can only access them via cross domain requests using Ajax? Right?

Comment: Yes you need to seperate it.